# Create combox as lookup field in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I create my first simple app with symfony 2 and struggle by creating a combobox 
for a lookup field.

The app consists of appointments which have a location. Every appointment
can have one location, the locations are shared with all appointments.

Here's my current work:

```
class Appointment
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    // other fields here

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $location;

    // more stuff here
}

/**
 * Location
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Location
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    // other fields here
}
```

Then, I created types for my classes:

```
class AppointmentType extends AbstractType
{
    ...
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            // other field here
            ->add('location', 'text')
        ;

        $builder->get('location')
          ->addModelTransformer(new LocationToNumberTransformer($this->manager));
    }
    ...
}
```

The `LocationToNumberTransformer` class transforms the location id to a text field.

Here's the html template:

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- other fields go here -->
  <div class="small-2 columns">{{ form_row(appointment.location) }}</div>
</div>
```

This all works fine. I can create appointments filling the location text field with
an valid id. Later the locations will just be a handful amount, so **I would like
to have a combobox or dropdown field which shows all available locations** and I can
select one.

I also created a simple location controller, which gives me a list of all locations:

```
class LocationsController extends Controller
{
    public function activeLocationsAsChoiceAction(Request $request, $selectedId = -1) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $locations = $em->createQuery('SELECT l FROM AppBundle:Location l')->execute();

        return $this->render('locations/active_list_as_choice.html.twig', array(
            'locations' => $locations,
            'selected_id' => $selectedId,
          ));
    }
}
```

With it, I can render a select input. Maybe, that's not necessary but eventually
I don't know, how to put the parts together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `entity` field type:

```
->add('location', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Class\Namespace\Location',
    'property' => 'name',
    'label' => 'choice_field_label',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->findAllLocationsForAppointmentForm(); 
        //Where findAllLocationsForAppointmentForm is the name of method in your
        //locationsRepo which returns queryBuilder, 
        //instead of this you could just write your custom query like
        //$qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('l');
        //$qb->andWhere(...);
        //return $qb;
    } 
))
```

If you need search functionality in your select field, then you can implement smth like `select2` jQuery lib.
**Links**:
[`entity` field type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/entity.html);
[`select2` examples page](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Comment: Thank you, I knew that it could be that easy but my search didn't find a clue in that direction.